# Wicket @SpringBean doesn't create serializable proxy

Tags: java, spring, wicket

```
@SpringBean
PDLocalizerLogic loc;
```

When using above I receive java.io.NotSerializableException. This is because loc is not serializable, but this shouldn't be problem because spring beans are a serializable proxies. 
I'm using wicket-spring library, and as injector SpringComponentInjector, where wrapInProxies is by default set to true, so I think that proxies should be created, but they aren't.

On the page https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/spring.html#Spring-AnnotationbasedApproach is written:

> Using annotation-based approach, you
>   should not worry about
>   serialization/deserialization of the
>   injected dependencies as this is
>   handled automatically, the
>   dependencies are represented by
>   serializable proxies

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: +1 simply because this is the first place I've heard wrapInProxies mentioned, and I managed to chase it down (didn't write the Application class myself) and it solved all my problems :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know how the bean is being injected?

1. Through component initialization (i.e. a Component and being filled in by the SpringComponentInjector)
2. Some other object using InjectorHolder.getInjector().inject(this)?
3. Injected directly by spring (i.e. this is a spring bean where the property is being set by Spring configuration)

Cases 1 and 2 would use wicket-spring integration and would wrap the bean with a wicket proxy which is serializable. 
Case 3 would only provide you whatever spring passes to you without wrapping.

Comment: Hmm..I'm using InjectorHolder.getInjector().inject(this) because the class isn't wicket component, so the bean should be serializable.

Comment: Then are you sure it is loc that is in violation of being not serializable? Is there something else here that is causing this?

Comment: It was my falt, I hadn't noticed that I had different config for Mock application (wrapInProxies set to false). I've changed it and everything works as expected. Sorry for bothering you!

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure your bean is really proxied. By default spring does not create proxies.

Second, check your proxying strategy - whether it is `proxy-target-class="true"` or not. If it is `false`, (afaik) a reference to your object is stored in the invocation handler of the JDK proxy, and is attempted to be serialized.

So you'll need to make your class `Serializable` as well, if you need it to be.

Comment: In this case, it is actually Wicket who should create the proxies (it uses CGLib under the covers for concrete classes, and regular Java proxies for interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

Can you double check that the instantiation listener is added in your application class:

addComponentInstantiationListener(new SpringComponentInjector(this));

Also, this only works for fields in Wicket components, not arbitrary classes.

See also [wicket @SpringBean can not create bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210496/wicket-springbean-can-not-create-bean)