# Injecting dependencies using @Autowired into objects created with "new ..."

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, wicket, autowired

I have a problem with injecting a bean into a helper class. It works basically like this: I create an object in the page constructor that does some work, returns some data and I show these on the page. In this helper object, a service should be injected via `@Autowired` annotation. However, I always get a null pointer exception when I use it. I also tried `@SpringBean` but it didn't help. On the other hand, when I inject this service directly into the page with `@SpringBean`, it's accessible and works fine. Do you know where the problem is?

This is the page:

```
public class Page extends BasePage {
    public Page() {
        HelperObject object = new HelperObject(new Application("APP_NAME"));
        String result = object.getData();

        add(new Label("label", result));
    }
}
```

Helper object:

```
public class HelperObject {
    private Application app;

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    public HelperObject(Application app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    public String getData() {
        // use service, manipulate data, return a string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@SpringBean` only injects dependencies into classes that inherit from Wicket's `Component`. `@Autowired` only injects dependencies into classes created by Spring itself. That means you can't automatically inject a dependency into an object you create with `new`.

(Edit: you can also add a `@SpringBean` injection to your class by injecting in the constructor:
`InjectorHolder.getInjector().inject(this);`)

My normal workaround for this is to use my application class to help. (I'm a little puzzled by your use of `new Application(...)`. I assume this isn't actually `org.apache.wicket.Application`.) For example:

```
public class MyApplication extends AuthenticatedWebApplication implements
    ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        throws BeansException {
        this.ctx = applicationContext;
    }

    public static MyApplication get() {
        return (MyApplication) WebApplication.get();
    }

    public static Object getSpringBean(String bean) {
        return get().ctx.getBean(bean);
    }

    public static <T> T getSpringBean(Class<T> bean) {
        return get().ctx.getBean(bean);
    }

    ....
}
```

In my Spring application context:

```
<!-- Set up wicket application -->
<bean id="wicketApplication" class="uk.co.humboldt.Project.MyApplication"/>
```

My helper object then looks up the service on demand:

```
public class HelperObject {

    private Service getService() {
        return MyApplication.getSpringBean(Service.class);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought after having played with it for a while. Is there a way to inject dependencies (using annotations) into objects that I create with `new...`? 
Yes, you're right, my `Application` object is a different one from the Wicket Application object.

Comment: Dependency injection needs some way to get hold of your newly created object. You can do this the Wicket way by inheriting from a base class which handles injection, or by having Spring create the object using a prototype scope: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

Comment: You should also be careful about keeping references to service objects in objects that Wicket will serialise in the session. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544802/wicket-springbean-doesnt-create-serializable-proxy/4737788#4737788

Comment: Also added an example of the `InjectorHolder` in constructor approach.

Answer (score 5):

You can inject dependencies into non-Spring-non-Wicket-new-created objects using `@SpringBean` by calling `InjectorHolder.getInjector().inject(this);` in its constructor.

For example:

```
class MyPojo {
    @SpringBean
    MyDumbDAO dao;
    MyPojo() {
        InjectorHolder.getInjector().inject(this);
    }
    void justDoIt() {
        dao.duh(); // dao is there!
    }
}
```

Note that it will only work if called within a Wicket-managed request. If not (ie, if it's a Quartz job, or a Filter executed before Wicket's), the `Application` instance will not be available, and the injector won't know how to get the dependencies.

Another solution is to use Spring's `@Configurable`. It uses AspectJ to intercept creation of annotated objects, and inject its dependencies, even if you instantiate them directly with `new` (or some other framework, like Hibernate, creates them internally). But this requires runtime or build-time (works better for me) bytecode manipulation, which may be too much magic for some people.

Answer (score 3):

The best practice would be to create your objects via a factory bean (that has those properties injected by Spring, and have that factory inject those properties to objects it spawns - pure IoC).

You should really **avoid using SpringContext all over the place** (or any other similar solution for that matter).
Here is a partial list of reasons:

1. Your code gets coupled with Spring way too much (low-cohesion).
2. You mix plumbing code with the business-logic.
3. Your code is less readable.
4. It's less maintainable (e.g., changing the name of the service bean would lead to code modification - this violates SRP & OCP).
5. It's less testable (e.g., you need the Spring framework to test it).