# initiate class explicitly on spring

Tags: java, spring

Suppose I have annotated a class `X` with `@Component` and somewhere else in my application I initiate this class explicitly by `new X()`.

Will this class still be managed by Spring?
And if not, is there a way to autowire another class `Y` inside this `X` class (that is not managed)?

Comment: 1/ No. 2/ I don't see why not (but you might want to post some code)

Comment: If you describe the reason why and the environment in which you want to do that, someone might have a suggestion on how to achieve it using Spring.

Comment: could be related: [Injecting dependencies using @Autowired into objects created with “new …”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5418945/217324)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and no.  For Spring to manage an object, it must be created as a bean or annotated with `@Component` (or its derivatives), and instantiated by the container.  You can only use `@Autowired` to inject dependencies into managed objects.  This injection happens when the container is starting up, so any non-managed object will fail to have its dependencies injected.

Comment: how does spring container know class X is being instantiated explicitly  ?