# How can I get a Spring bean injected in my custom Wicket model class?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, wicket

In a custom Wicket class, not unlike the following, I'm using a service bean which should be injected by Spring, as defined with the SpringBean annotation (from the wicket-spring project).

```
public class ReportExportFileModel extends AbstractReadOnlyModel<File> {

    @SpringBean(name = "reportService")
    ReportService reportService;

    ReportDto reportDto;

    ReportExportFileModel(ReportDto reportDto) {
        this.reportDto = reportDto;
    }

    @Override
    public File getObject() {
        try {
            return reportService.generatePentahoReport(reportDto);
        } catch (ReportGenerationException e) {
           // ...
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work: `reportService.generatePentahoReport()` fails with NullPointerException, because **the bean has not been injected by Spring for some reason**.

Curiously, I've used the exact same Model code as anonymous inner class on a Wicket Page, and there was no problem there.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The wicket dependency-injection works with classes implementing IComponentInstantiationListener. These application-level listeners are called whenever a Component is instantiated. This is the hook used for dependency injection of components.

The model classes do not have such a mechanism in place. Any model can directly implement IModel so there is no abstract base class which can call the listeners, unlike Component.

I use the following base class for my injected models (Wicket 1.5):

```
public abstract class InjectedDetachableModel<T> extends LoadableDetachableModel<T> {

    public InjectedDetachableModel() {
        Injector.get().inject(this);
    }

    public InjectedDetachableModel(T a_entity) {
        super(a_entity);
        Injector.get().inject(this);
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
Summary of relevant differences between 1.4 and 1.5, taken from [Wicket 1.5 migration guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html):

### Wicket 1.4

```
@Override
protected void init()
{
    // initialize Spring
    addComponentInstantiationListener(new SpringComponentInjector(this, applicationContext));
}
```

and

```
InjectorHolder.getInjector().inject(Object object)
```

### Wicket 1.5:

```
@Override
protected void init()
{
    // initialize Spring
    getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this, applicationContext))
}
```

and

```
Injector.get().inject(Object object)
```

Comment: This is Wicket 1.5 while Jonik still uses 1.4.

Comment: Yeah, @martin-g is right; forgot to mention it in the question, but I'm on 1.4.17. If you edit your answer to cover both 1.4 and 1.5, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 7):

Apparently Spring beans don't get automatically injected to *other classes than Pages*. I've run to this also with my custom WebRequestCycle class.

One easy solution is to trigger the injection manually using `InjectorHolder.getInjector().inject(this)`.

So, writing the constructor like this makes the model work as intended:

```
ReportExportFileModel(ReportDto reportDto) {
    this.reportDto = reportDto;
    InjectorHolder.getInjector().inject(this);
}
```

**Edit**: ah, right after posting this, I found another SO question [with a more accurate explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210496/wicket-springbean-can-not-create-bean/3210900#3210900) of what's going on:

> @SpringBean works only in any subclass of Component.

Comment: If anyone knows better solutions, or can explain why wicket-spring  integration works like this, feel free to post other answers!

Comment: bernie explained how it works. I can only add that in Wicket 1.5.3+ also Behavior is auto-injected like o.a.w.Component.

Comment: Sorry for discussion like old-mafia-war ;) , Pls remember me WHY models cannot have been injected, has this decision deep philosophical background, or only implementation feature? AND HOW is orthodox wicket solution form models, resources etc

Comment: Self answer: because based on interface, not class. :)