# Regarding Spring's @Autowired and Wicket's @SpringBean

Tags: spring, annotations, wicket

I am currently looking into integrating Mockito and JUnit into my Wicket/Spring/Hibernate project and have found a tutorial on how to do this using annotations.

Trouble is I am unfamiliar with @Autowired and after a look on google I am finding it hard to see the difference between this annotation and the @SpringBean annotation.

Are they one in the same or is there a difference I should be aware of ?

My code to offer some context to this question:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txManager", defaultRollback = false) 
public class TestHome
{
private WicketTester tester;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext ctx;

@Autowired
private WebApplication webApplication;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    tester = new WicketTester(webApplication);
}

@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
public void testRenderHomePage() {
    tester.startPage(Home.class);
    tester.assertRenderedPage(Home.class);
    tester.assertComponent("home", Home.class);
}

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Wicket SpringComponentInjector, it uses its own injection. The @Autowired annotation is a Springframework annotation, but Wicket SpringComponentInjector ignores that. So the Wicket annotation is @SpringBean that marks a field to be autowired (injected) by Spring bean or component that has to exist in Spring context.

In you code snippet you use the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner runner, so your fields are injected by Spring, so it is correct.

See an example, how to use SpringComponentInjector at [How can I get a Spring bean injected in my custom Wicket model class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155359/how-can-i-get-a-spring-bean-injected-in-my-custom-wicket-model-class)