# wicket,spring jpa repository - nullpointer on @Autowire

Tags: spring, hibernate, web-applications, wicket, spring-data-jpa

Im trying to build an application based on wicket, Spring jpa repositories, and Mysql.

The problem is, my Service classes just don't want to autowire. I got a nullpointer exception if i want to use my autowired class.

**In fact, i got double nullpointer: My BaseServiceConfig.java doesnt autowire the implementation, and the autowired repository in the itnerface is also null. So, the question is why.**

> ```
> public final class ArmyBuilderPanel extends Panel {
>
> @Autowired
> DiskService diskService; //--> frist null, before setting it.
>
> public ArmyBuilderPanel(String id) {
>     super(id);
>     add(new Label("armyPanel", "Content placeholder: Army builder panel"));
>     diskService = new DiskServiceImpl();
>     diskService.save(new Disk()); //--> second nullpointer
> } }
> ```

Im trying to do this with minimal to no xml, all the coniguration was done in java classes. Let me show you the code:

**Repository interface:**

> ```
>  @Transactional
>  public interface DiskRepository extends JpaRepository<Disk, Long> {
>  }
> ```

**Service itnerface:**

> ```
> public interface DiskService {
>
> public Disk save(Disk entity);
>
> }
> ```

Service impementation:

> ```
> @Service 
> public class DiskServiceImpl implements DiskService {
>
> @Autowired
> DiskRepository diskRepo;
>
> @Override
> public Disk save(Disk entity) {
>     return diskRepo.save(entity);
> }
>
> }
> ```

**BaseServiceConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"hu.diskwars"})
public class BaseServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    DiskService diskService() {
        return new DiskServiceImpl();
    }

}
```

**PersistenceJPAConfig.java**

> ```
>  @Configuration 
>  @EnableTransactionManagement
>  @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"hu.diskwars"}) public class
>  PersistenceJPAConfig implements DisposableBean {
>
> @Bean
> public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
>     LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
>     em.setDataSource(dataSource());
>     em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"hu.diskwars"});
>
>     JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
>     em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
>     em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
>
>     return em;
> }
>
> @Bean
> public DataSource dataSource() {
>     DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
>     dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
>     dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/whdiskwars_db");
>     dataSource.setUsername("Westy");
>     dataSource.setPassword("pass");
>     return dataSource;
> }
>
> @Bean
> public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
>     JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
>     transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
>     return transactionManager;
> }
>
> @Bean
> public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
>     return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
> }
>
> Properties additionalProperties() {
>     return new Properties() {
>         {  // Hibernate Specific:
>             setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
>             setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
>         }
>     };
> }
>
> @Override
> public void destroy() throws Exception {
>     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
> } }
> ```

**BaseServiceConfig.java (autowiring the implementation)**

> ```
> @Configuration @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"hu.diskwars"})
> public class BaseServiceConfig {
>
> @Bean
> DiskService diskService() {
>     return new DiskServiceImpl();
> }
>
> }
> ```

web.xml

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-app version="2.5"
> xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
> 
>   <display-name>diskwars</display-name>
>           <context-param>
>       <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
>       <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
>   </context-param>
> 
>   <context-param>
>       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>       <param-value>hu.diskwars.config</param-value>   </context-param>
> 
>   <listener>
>       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
>   </listener>
>           <filter>        <filter-name>wicket.diskwars</filter-name>      <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
>       <init-param>            <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
>           <param-value>hu.diskwars.view.application.WicketApplication</param-value>
>       </init-param>   </filter>
> 
>   <filter-mapping>        <filter-name>wicket.diskwars</filter-name>
>       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   </filter-mapping>   </web-app>
```

pom.xml:

> ```
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
>
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>   <groupId>hu.dwdb</groupId>
>   <artifactId>diskwars</artifactId>
>   <packaging>war</packaging>
>   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>   <name>diskwars</name>
>   <description></description>
>
>   <properties>
>       <wicket.version>6.13.0</wicket.version>
>       <jetty.version>7.6.13.v20130916</jetty.version>
>       <wtp.version>none</wtp.version>
>                 <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
>                 <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
>                 <jpa.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</jpa.version>
>                 <hibernate.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.version>
>                 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>   </properties>
>
>   <dependencies>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring.version}</version>
>           <type>jar</type>
>       </dependency>
>
>                 <dependency>
>                     <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
>                     <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
>                     <version>${jpa.version}</version>
>                     <type>jar</type>
>                 </dependency>
>
>       <!--  WICKET DEPENDENCIES -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
>           <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
>           <version>${wicket.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
>           <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
>           <version>${wicket.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- LOGGING DEPENDENCIES - LOG4J -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>           <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
>           <version>1.6.4</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>log4j</groupId>
>           <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
>           <version>1.2.16</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!--  JUNIT DEPENDENCY FOR TESTING -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>junit</groupId>
>           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>           <version>4.11</version>
>           <scope>test</scope>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!--  JETTY DEPENDENCIES FOR TESTING  -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
>           <version>${jetty.version}</version>
>           <scope>provided</scope>
>       </dependency>
>
>                 <!--  HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES  -->
>                 <dependency>
>                       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>                       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
>                       <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
>                 </dependency>
>
>                 <dependency>
>                       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>                       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
>                        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
>                 </dependency>
>
>                  <!--  MYSQL DRIVER  -->
>                 <dependency>
>                       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
>                       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
>                       <version>5.1.29</version>
>                 </dependency>
>   </dependencies>
>
>
>   <build>
>       <resources>
>           <resource>
>               <filtering>false</filtering>
>               <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
>           </resource>
>           <resource>
>               <filtering>false</filtering>
>               <directory>src/main/java</directory>
>               <includes>
>                   <include>**</include>
>               </includes>
>               <excludes>
>                   <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
>               </excludes>
>           </resource>
>       </resources>
>       <testResources>
>           <testResource>
>               <filtering>false</filtering>
>               <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
>           </testResource>
>           <testResource>
>               <filtering>false</filtering>
>               <directory>src/test/java</directory>
>               <includes>
>                   <include>**</include>
>               </includes>
>               <excludes>
>                   <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
>               </excludes>
>           </testResource>
>       </testResources>
>
>       <plugins>
>           <plugin>
>               <inherited>true</inherited>
>               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>               <version>2.5.1</version>
>               <configuration>
>                   <source>1.6</source>
>                   <target>1.6</target>
>                   <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
>                   <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
>                   <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
>               </configuration>
>           </plugin>
>
>           <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
>               <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>               <version>${jetty.version}</version>
>               <configuration>
>                   <connectors>
>                       <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
>                           <port>8080</port>
>                           <maxIdleTime>3600000</maxIdleTime>
>                       </connector>
>                       <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
>                           <port>8443</port>
>                           <maxIdleTime>3600000</maxIdleTime>
>                           <keystore>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/keystore</keystore>
>                           <password>wicket</password>
>                           <keyPassword>wicket</keyPassword>
>                       </connector>
>                   </connectors>
>               </configuration>
>           </plugin>
>
>           <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>               <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
>               <version>2.9</version>
>               <configuration>
>                   <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
>                   <wtpversion>${wtp.version}</wtpversion>
>               </configuration>
>           </plugin>
>       </plugins>
>   </build>
>
>   <repositories>
>       <repository>
>           <id>Apache Nexus</id>
>           <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
>           <releases>
>               <enabled>false</enabled>
>           </releases>
>           <snapshots>
>               <enabled>true</enabled>
>           </snapshots>
>       </repository>
>   </repositories>
>   </project>
> ```

Here is a picture of my workspace:

Thanks for the help!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P32oV.png

## EDIT:

- Added SpringInjector to my base wicket application

  @Override
  public void init() {
      super.getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this));
  }
- And suddenly a completly new, error pops out, in conncetion with my persistance unit.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [hu/diskwars/config/PersistenceJPAConfig.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting persistence unit
>   definitions for name 'diskwarsPU':
>   file:/D:/Development/projects/diskwars/target/diskwars-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/,
>   file:/D:/Development/projects/diskwars/target/diskwars-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/

The main problem is, i dont even have a persistance.xml file. I used to (with the same exact name 'diskwarsPU', but i throw it out, when i got to know, that i can do all the configurations without it.
I cleaned, builded the project again, even deleted the target folder, no use.

Comment: It looks you try to create the same bean twice. I guess it's the package scanning.

Answer (score 2):

Wicket know really nothing about Spring @Autowired annotation. Use Wicket @SpringBean annotation and SringComponentInjector to inject a Sring bean into Wicket components.

The full example how to use @SpringBean annotation is in question [How can I get a Spring bean injected in my custom Wicket model class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155359/how-can-i-get-a-spring-bean-injected-in-my-custom-wicket-model-class)

Comment: Thanks for yor answer, but neither my service class gets injected, wich has nothing to do with wicket. (DiskServiceImpl). Im guessing, there is another error in there, or im just simply not getting the idea.

Comment: Please, provide your stacktrace.