# Autowired field remains null causing WicketRuntime Exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, wicket, autowired

There are tons of these questions but suggested solutions doesnt seem to work for me.
Im useing wicket along with hibernate and spring. Im trying simple form with one textfield but wicket keeps complaining abou `NullPointerException` which comes from autowired field being null

**Wicket class**

```
public class WebLoginPage extends WebPage {
    @SpringBean
    IUserService userService;

    private final User newUser = new User();

    RequiredTextField<String> username = new RequiredTextField<String>(
            "username", new PropertyModel<String>(this.newUser, "username"));

    public WebLoginPage() {
        final Form<?> form = new Form<User>("userForm") {

            @Override
            protected void onSubmit() {
                WebLoginPage.this.userService
                        .addUser(WebLoginPage.this.newUser);
            }

        };
        form.add(this.username);
        this.add(form);

    }
```

**UserServiceImpl**

```
package com.ziker.schedule.service;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.ziker.schedule.dao.IUserDao;
import com.ziker.schedule.pojo.User;

@Controller
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService, Serializable {

    @Autowired
    IUserDao userDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addUser(User user) {
        this.userDao.saveUser(user);

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        this.userDao.deleteUser(user);

    }
}
```

**UserDaoImpl**

```
package com.ziker.schedule.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.ziker.schedule.pojo.User;

@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements IUserDao {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(user);
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return this.sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

**applicationContext.XML**

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

     <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schedule"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="rootroot"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.ziker.schedule.pojo.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDao" class="com.ziker.schedule.dao.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userService" class="com.ziker.schedule.service.UserServiceImpl">  

    </bean>



</beans>
```

**Wicket webpage**

> package com.ziker.schedule.schedule;
>
> import org.apache.wicket.Page; import
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication; import
>   org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringComponentInjector;
>
> import com.ziker.schedule.login.WebLoginPage;
>
> public class ScheduleApplication extends WebApplication
>
> {
>
> @Override   public Class getHomePage() {        return
>   WebLoginPage.class;   }
>
> }

Any help will be appreciated ive tried also configuration without annotations with no luck. To me it seems that im missing some little thing but after one and half day i had to ask

EDIT: Problematic field is`IUserService userService;` in WebLogin Page

stacktrace

```
[qtp14429558-16] ERROR org.apache.wicket.DefaultExceptionMapper - Unexpected error occurred
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onFormSubmitted of interface org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener targeted at [Form [Component id = userForm]] on component [Form [Component id = userForm]] threw an exception
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:216)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:837)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ziker.schedule.login.WebLoginPage$1.onSubmit(WebLoginPage.java:30)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1262)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:934)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:766)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:700)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: you didnt mention which autowired field is null, also thr are no logs

Comment: i updated question but i believe stacktrace will not be helpful but again maybe im missing something

Comment: have you overridden wickets application init() method to add SpringComponentInjector ?

Comment: well this is good point im missing this in my init. But after little googling compiler isnt recognizing `addComponentInstantiationListener(new SpringComponentInjector(this));` im using Wicket 7.0.0 whats the solution for this version ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155359/how-can-i-get-a-spring-bean-injected-in-my-custom-wicket-model-class

Comment: thank you sir it helped me out i updated my answer with core wicket class where the problem in init() method was  if you want you can rewrite your comment into answer and ill accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add SpringComponentInjector by overriding Wickets application init() method to inject spring beans.